# Why can't I print "Hello World" in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make a page for my website to add experience on my profile. But when I clicked the submit button on `add-experience.html` the system redirects me to `/Add-Experience-2` but I can not print the "Hello World" text.

```js
app.post("/Add-Experience-:useremail",function(req,res){


    fs.readFile("user-profile(change-settings)/Experience/Add-Experience/add-experience.html","utf-8",function(err,data){

        if(err){

            throw err;
        }

        else{

            res.write(data);

            res.end();
        }
    });
});


app.post("/Add-Experience-2",function(req,res){

    console.log("Hello World");
});
```

I am sure that the "useremail" parameter is not null nor empty.What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is the request perhaps invoking the `/Add-Experience-:useremail` endpoint instead?  What is the server's response to the POST request?  If the response is that HTML file contents then it's hitting the first endpoint, not the second one.  (The second one never sends a response, so the browser should just hang and/or time out.)  I'd recommend giving the endpoints less ambiguous URLs.

Comment: It actually works when I remove the parameter and write an email ("/Add-Experience-:useremail"-"/Add-Experience-johndoe@gmail.com")

Comment: Try adding a comment to see if the first endpoint is hit. I'm pretty sure the routing does hit the first endpoint. Try changing the name of the second endpoint.

Comment: @cihantoker: Ok, but what exactly “doesn’t work” here?  The second endpoint doesn’t do anything, so if you’re receiving a response then you’re invoking the first endpoint.  Taking a step back… What is the purpose of these two endpoints?  What is each one for?  Neither of them do anything that a POST request would be used for.  Why do they need to be ambiguously named?  What is the goal behind that?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `user-experience-:useremail` and `user-experience-2` resolve to the first `:useremail` parameter. If I recall correctly, you can just change the order of them in the file and it should work. If not, you should use a different route.